# Will tf.loadFrozenModel and tf.loadModel have different prediction time?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Assume that the model trained in tensorflow uses two methods to convert the models available to tensorflowjs:
1) Use the tf.saved_model.simple_save method to save the model in tensorflow, then use tf.loadFrozenModel to load the model in tensorflowjs and predict the result using model.predict
2) Use keras(sequence) to save the model in tensorflow, then use tf.loadModel to load the model in tensorflowjs and predict the result using model.predict

If you train the same model in tensorflow, but different save methods. In the tensorflowjs to use the above 2 load model method to predict the results, will the time difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same architecture in both tensorflowJs and keras, the inference time using tensorflowJs will be alike. tensorflowJs converter will just construct a graph of your topology and the weights. So in both cases the processing time is roughly the same